# Unix - Find files that are at least writable by the owner and readable by others

Tags: regex, shell, unix

find -perm [2|3|6|7].[4|5|6|7]

I'm trying to let the parameter of -perm to match a pattern of [2|3|6|7].[4|5|6|7], but I don't know exactly how should I write this...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
find -perm -204
```

Note the dash in -204.  It means that all of the digits in permission mode must be satisfied.

You can find more detail [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm).

Comment: But as it is 'at least' rather than 'exactly', shouldn't I try let it match a pattern? Because combinations like 377, 744 would also do, right?

Comment: @Zoe You don't need an exact match on all bits -- only on those that describe the permissions you want the check. 204 covers 304, 604, and 704, for example.

Comment: @Zoe Also, `find` doesn't accept "patterns" in the argument to `-perm`.